# Deriving the color correction matrix with OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix

I want to find color correction matrix with OpenCV using C++. I have 16*32 leds with different colors in led array and I know the actual (B, G, R) values of them. Then working led array is recorded with video and I can get the pixel values(B', G', R') of video. The relation between (B, G, R) and (B', G', R') is color correction matrix.([process is similar to here](http://www.imatest.com/docs/colormatrix/)) how I find the pixel in the image that corresponds to the LED? If I know the this, I can achieve the color correction matrix which converts the (B', G', R') to (B, G, R).
Any suggestion will be very helpful.

**EDIT**

Is there any OpenCV function or sample code to find the nearest values of (B, G, R) -for example (0,0,255)- in frame?  I realized that nearest values becomes (B', G', R')

Comment: It would help if you could attach an image that you are trying to process.

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com)! It is unclear what you are asking. Are you asking how to calculate the colour correction given `(B, G, R)` and `(B', G', R')`, or how to find the pixel in the image that corresponds to the LED? I think the main confusion is the sentence "How can I detect place of pixel according to led?" What do you mean by "place"?

Comment: @MikeOunsworth: There is a question: "How can I detect place of pixel according to led?"

Comment: Let me explain with an example. I have a red operating led on led array, I know its (B, G, R) value (0,0,255). I displayed it with webcam on computer. I want to find the actual pixel represents the red led on frame. If I find it, I will achieve its values (B', G', R'). Finally, I can calculate color correction matrix. I hope "How can I detect place of pixel according to led?" is reasonable right now. -This is only example, I want to find place of 256 different color in frame, not just red-  @And I only have video now, I could add photo on Monday.

Answer (score 0):

I assume, the mechanical test-setup is static (camera is always in the same position relative to led-panel)

In this case, define the coordinates and the regions of the LEDs manually. E.g. create a binary mask having 1 on the regions where LED-intensity should be evaluated. With such a mask you could evaluate LED intensities using simple rectangular regions.

**EDIT**

Finding a single LED, when all others are off is done by simple thresholding, finding the contour and calculating center of the contour. If you post an image, you'll certainly get the code-example.

I would suggest, before you start implementing auto recognitions of the coordinates and colors, make some tests.

Plot the intensities of LEDs and their calculated values. Find out, what makes more impact on the calculated (by OpenCV) value the actual intensity or the lightning conditions, angle to the camera, region of the camera, a particular camera (if the software will be used with several cameras), temperature, how long the camera was operating, etc.
Start implementing the software only if you'll fing a satisfactory correspondence/accuracy between set and measured values.

P.S.
I wouldn't rely on the automatic calculation, if I had chance to simplify the things.

Comment: I don't want to do any manual thing but can you please give me more information about your idea in case I couldn't get the solution.